# How to load tree store form ajax response

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have defined my tree code here in `ExtJS`. I declare my `store` there in the `treepanel` definition.

**Here is my code.**

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    useArrows: true,
    autoScroll: false,
    animate: true,
    animateShadow: true,
    enableDD: false,
    id: 'myTreePanel',
    rootVisible: false,
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [],
        }
    })
}
```

From the response, I am getting my data like this. Can anyone help me to load the data in `ExtJS` Tree panel.

```
myTreeData = [{
    children: [],
    text: 'text1'
}, {
    children: [],
    text: 'text2'
}, {
    children: [{
        children: null,
        text: 'text31'
    }, {
        children: null,
        text: 'text32'
    }],
    text: 'text3'
}, {
    children: [],
    text: 'text4'
}, {
    children: [],
    text: 'text5'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `store.setRootNode(myTreeData)`.